# fair disivion of indivisibles with qualification constraint

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, fair-division

Let there be $n$ indivisible heterogenous items.
Let there be $m$ agents.
The subjective utility functions of the agents are additive and identical.   i.e $\forall X,i,j\ V_i(X) = V_j(X)$.

The additional constraint is:
there are agents that some items cannot be assigned to them (i.e the qualification constraint)

This can be defined by a matrix $Q \in Z_2^{m,n}$
where $Q_{i, j} = 1$ iff agent *i* is qualified to be assigned item *m*.

### The task

I would like to be able to do the following:

1. define some fairness criterion that matches the problem
2. find an algorithm that provides an allocation that implements it.

I believe that due to the qualification constraint some standard fairness criteria, like $EF1$, may not exist. This is why I am also asking for a fairness criterion.

Comment: I think where it says "e.g." you mean "i.e."?

Comment: You are correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can define the problem as an optimization problem, and than solve it using a suitable solver.

define $X \in Z_2^{m, n}$ as the decision variable.
$X_{i, j} = 1$ will denote that item j was decided to be assigned to agent i and $X_{i, j} = 0$ will denote the opposite.

Therefore the optimization problem is the following:
$$ \text{minimize f(X)}$$
$$ \text{subject to } \forall j \sum_i X_{i, j} = 1$$
$$ \ \quad\qquad\qquad \sum_{i, j} X \circ Q = n $$
where $f(X)$ is the fairness objective.

the first constraint ensures every item is assigned to exactly one agent.
the second constraint ensures that the qualification constraint is satisfied.

As for the fairness objective, I decided to minimize the amount of envy.
 therefore $f(X)$ is defined as:
$$f(X) = max(Xv) - min(Xv)$$
where $v = [v_1, v_2, ... v_n]^t$ is the vector of the values of the items.

Other fairness objectives could be used as long as they are convex.

this optimization problem is a non-linear mixed integer programming problem and can be solved by using suitable solvers.  An example for a solver is the python library [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/).
[here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#mixed-integer-programs) is the part it discusses mixed integer programming